# How to seed data in migration that Id increment automatically in ef core 3?

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, migration, seeding

I use below code in OnModelCreating method of dataContext:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<EnumValue>().HasData(
            new EnumValue
            {
                EnumValueId = 1,
                EnumValueName ="test"
            });
```

But I dont want to set EnumValueId = 1 manually, I want make it automatically.
Here is my EnumValue model:

```
[Key]
[Required]
public int EnumValueId { get; set; }
[Required]
public string EnumValueName { get; set; }
```

How to make Id property automatically increment?

Comment: have you tried it yourself (without setting the id manually)? By convention, the key property ending with `Id` and has type of `int` should be auto-increment by default (no additional configuration required). Unless you have some existing database that is not created from the models (not using code first approach). If that's the case, you need to manually modify your database table.

Comment: @KingKing I tied, I got error that says Id can not be non zero value. I also read documentation, yu should declare Id if dont want to write custom migration

Comment: it's a strange behavior which may be changed across versions of EFCore. Anyway you can try finding some method to configure the key property explicitly as identity, as for `SQL Server`, we have something like `modelBuilder.Entity<EnumValue>().Property(e => e.EnumValueId).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn()` - for `postgresql`, it should have some similar extension method (implemented by the corresponding EFCore provider for postgresql).

Comment: note that after any update to the configuration or model, you need to run the db update via the auto-generated migrations. Otherwise you must update the db manually (which may be error-prone causing mismatching between the db and the models).

Comment: I have found a partial solution for the HasData needing to specify the Id when adding data using HasData.  Rather than specifying the id directly I use a variable (say id) and ++id for every new object created in the HasData    int id = 0  `entity.HasData(  
        new Book{
            Id = ++id, 
            Title = "Computer Science in the 80's",
            ...
        }, 
        new Book{
            Id = ++id, 
            Title = "Information Systems in the 2000's",
            ...
        }, 

    );`
Hope this helps others with trying to maintain the id's generated

Comment: plus you need to ensure that all new Data entries are always added at the end as the initial id values can not changes on subsequent migration files

Answer (score 1):

> The primary key value needs to be specified even if it's usually
> generated by the database. It will be used to detect data changes
> between migrations.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding